# Activating a Phonegap application using the power/volume button

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am currently developing an Android application using Phonegap, which involves sending text messages. Is there any way I can directly make my app start running if the power/volume button is pressed twice?

For example, let's say the phone is locked and the screen is off. When I double press (or single press, or "any-other-recognizable-number" press the power/volume button, I want the app to start up in the background and send a text message. Preferably, unlocking the phone should not be required.

I have seen multiple questions about this, but they either don't implement Phonegap, or they haven't been answered. How can I implement this in Phonegap?